# in the build project process what is the meaning of skipped=1

Tags: c#, build, compilation

I have a solution with the main project, helping project and installation project

When I build or rebuild the main project I get:

```
Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped
```

Now since the helping project generate the following message:

```
Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped
```

I don't understand what is being skipped (I have 1 success in the main file ... so 1 out of 1 ?!)

What's wrong and how can i fix it?

Thanks
Asaf

Comment: Is your main project really depending on the helping project? That may have an influence on the build order.

Answer (score 1):

Each project (csproj-file or other project-type like setup-project) in your solution should correspond to 1 build-item.
If an item is skipped, it is not needed in your current build. For example: if you build your main program, the setup-project will not be compiled, because the program does not depend on it.
You can also configure multiple build configurations, where in some configurations certain projects are not build, e.g. in your debug-config you can leave out the setup, or in your release-config you may leave out some unit test libs.

Comment: what you say doesn't add up with the results I get :helping project: Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped...Main project: Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped... installation project:  Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 1 skipped... or does it make sense to you?

Comment: I would read it as:
Build main project: main project succeeded, helping-project skipped, installation project does not appear because it's after the build project in the build order.
Build helping project: helping project succeeded, all others don't appear, again because they are after the built project in the build order